# Should I use SOAP or REST to automate external web service searching?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, automation, web

I hope to create an application which will send a barcode serial to this database:

http://www.upcdatabase.com/itemform.asp

which is a universal barcode repository for foods.

The food description is then returned to my application, which I will then identify the keyword of the food product, for example yogurt.

Once I have this keyword, I take it to this webpage:

http://nutridb.org/

And enter it into the search field, returning the nutritional values of the item, which I will then extract and present as information in my application.

I have been researching online and am confused as to how I can automate this process. Is it possible this can be done using REST and SOAP?

Answer (score 0):

That upcdatabase site you mention has an XML-RPC interface to it, so I would say you are probably limited to that.  You could use a RESTful approach to screen scrape but I looked at the HTML and there is little or no semantic markup in the HTML so it is going to be hard.

Comment: Hi Darrel, thanks for the reply. The concept of automation and web scraping as a whole is completely new to me, so I apologize in advance if any of the following seems stupid!: When you say a site has a xml-rpc interface, how is this determined? Also, regarding the semantic markup of the UPC webpage, there is a <Description> tag, which I would use to extract the product name - this is about all the automating done with this upc database - could you recommend any technologies that may be of use with this process?

Comment: @MindDrip The XML-RPC interface is advertised on the front page.  See http://www.upcdatabase.com/xmlrpc.asp  There is a `<td><td>Description</td><td>...</td>` block of HTML but which you could hunt for, it would just be a bit fragile.